# SQLite why we copy db in assets folder

Tags: android, sqlite

There is a confusion .

In so many example i found they are coping `database` in `assets` folder.

I don't know why they are doing .and what is the benefit of doing that.

will any one explain this.please

Thanks.

Comment: Nezam we are not playing here one word explanation.can u say in detail.

Comment: user cant able to delete the db file when the db is in assert folder

Comment: kumar your means is that if i make db in sdcard and i am coping in assets folder ....i can not delete the file which is in sdcard

Comment: Means, if you are copying the db in assert folder, then it is the part of apk file. So user cannot modify/delete the data.

Answer (score 4):

A database with default data and table structure is often prebuilt and included in the assets folder. We then copy this from the assets folder to the internal or external storage at runtime, as the assets folder is ready only after compile time, and we cannot modify the data in it. Therefore, to be able to write to the database form our app, we must first copy it to a part of the storage we can access.

Comment: Raghav if i want my database in external storage.

Comment: @CobraHissssHissss..... Then just copy it from your assets using normal Java IO. Keep in mind that if you put it on the external storage, any and every app with permission to that storage can access it.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, you may want to have db with prepared data. Think about address book, or zip code things. If you don't put that information in asset folder, building basic information would be a pain (Of course, you can get data via network, but that's not the point)

Answer (score 0):

There are some good reasons like:

1- Its easy to create your Database outside `Android` envirnment using some GUI tool like `SQLiteBrowser` etc.

2- If you want to have some `default` data, you can do it easily. You can insert insert your deafult data outside `Android envirenment`.